# Selenium запуск с proxy Socks5

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, proxy, firefox

Стоит задача запустить веб-драйвер с прокси socks5. Нашел вот такой код:

```
proxy = '62.33.207.201:80'

caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
caps['marionette'] = True

caps['proxy'] = {
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "httpProxy": proxy,
    "ftpProxy": proxy,
    "sslProxy": proxy
}

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
```

Но у меня прокси вида `ip:port` и `login:pass`. Как для моей задачи изменить этот код?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55582859/12785139

Comment: @D.Violet это код для хрома, но тут он тоже будет работать, думаю. Просто это выглядит, как костыль, мне нужно будет в цикле менять прокси не один раз, а этот вариант довольно затратный по времени. Неужели нет никаких решений, чтобы со старта запускать прокси, просто передав параметры?

Comment: насколько известно этот метод убрали: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42633506/12785139., посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/a/59288186/12785139

Comment: @D.Violet к сожалению это не помогло :(
способ через `selenium-wire` кидает ошибку соединения, хотя прокси рабочий, остальные способы тоже не работают